# .htaccess multiple parameters is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with htaccess rule because is not working. I already try to find any solution on google but still have not found yet. 
The code is:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /deshop/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/deshop/admin(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ admin/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^\s]+)$ index.php?p=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

The urls are working normally:

```
http://localhost/deshop/index.php to http://localhost/deshop/ -> home page from folder
http://localhost/deshop/admin/index.php to http://localhost/deshop/admin/ -> admin page from subfolder
http://localhost/deshop/index.php?p=tshirts to http://localhost/deshop/tshirts/
http://localhost/deshop/index.php?p=brand&b=John%20Player to http://localhost/deshop/brand/John-Player/
```

So that happen, last rule does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

But last rule has worked yet. I really difficult. I want get url with parameters so look work :

```
http://localhost/deshop/index.php?p=single&id=0005 to http://localhost/deshop/single/0005
```

Or, what am I wrong? Any solution? Can you help me? Thanks a lot. By the way, my english is not good. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved it.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/miistore/miiadmin$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ miiadmin/index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/?single/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?p=single&id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?brand/([^\s]+)/?$ index.php?p=brand&b=$1 [L,QSA]
```